# Documents Similarity between a gruop of text files

Tags: python

I need to do the following algorithm:

1. read a group of text files
2. search for a word in the files
3. print a binary matrix that has 1 if the word exists and 0 if it does not exist.
4. The problem is with reading the text files

Code:

```
import os 
fileList = os.listdir('C:\Users\user\Desktop\Documents') 
for eachFile in fileList: 
    with open(eachFile, 'rb') as _fp:
        fileData = _fp.read()
        print("FILE DATA (%s):\n\n%s\n\n"%(_fp.name, fileData)
```

Comment: the word will be entered by the user

Comment: Can you show what you have tried?

Comment: @AghyadSkaif Please edit your question to include your comment above, with the code formatted appropriately.

Comment: I've posted the code in the question, thank u :)